# How to destroy instance of MagicSuggest JQ plugin?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, magicsuggest

I'm using MagicSuggest in my forms, and found myself in cases where i need to destroy it and restore the input field.. went through the whole documentation, can't seem to find a way to do this...

regards

Comment: Did you go through the source code as well? What is your question?

Comment: didn't go through source anymore, hoping someone here knows already or can confirm that it can't be done, so as to save me some time .. as for the question, it's in the title and pretty clear already in my post. tnx

Comment: Then you should at the very least provide a link to that plugin. About your question not being clear: you say what you want to do is not documented as being possible, are you okay with that? You may get answers that will break on the next release of your plugin.

Comment: What do you mean by "restore the input field"? What if the component had multiple values selected, what should happen to the restored input field? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Hi karl.. simply put, when your plugin is attached to the input field, the input field seems to get replaced or altered or whatever... what if I want that input field RESTORED so that it acts like a regular input field again w/o the MS plugin? that's what im trying to do..

Comment: I'm still having a hard time seeing what you're trying to do. The input field/container div is altered whenever you instanciate the magicsuggest component on it. If you don't want the component, don't instanciate it, no? Can you make a jsfiddle of what you are trying to achieve perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

yes you are right. There is no easy way to revert the MagicSuggest field instance.

However, with jQuery, you can just remove the MagicSuggest DOM element, and replace the exact same input field to the correct position, and so it is "restored".

You can also get the MagicSuggest value before you completely remove the DOM element, and insert the value to the original input field.

You will also need to fix the CSS if needed.